# sed + how to get the second word (string) after "=" separator by sed

Tags: sed

how to get the second word (string) after "=" separator by sed (need to ignore spaces)

for example

```
   echo " bla bla word word1 = strin1 string2 " | sed .....
```

I should  get string2

another example

```
    echo " bla bla word word1 =swhsw 123  " | sed .....
```

I should get 123

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe `awk` is a better solution for this case, simply use.

```
echo "bla bla word word1 = strin1 string2" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: after I perfrom echo "bla bla word word1 = strin1 string2" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' I get  strin1 string2 (why its not print only string2 ?)

Comment: hi anders : I need only the second word after seperator not all words after seperator , can you change your awk according to that
lidia

Comment: @lidia fixed. In the example it prints string2.

Comment: OP asked for SED specific solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ echo " bla bla word word1 = strin1 string2 " | sed 's/.[^=]*=\(.[^ \t]*\)[ \t]*\(.[^ \t]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'
string2


$ echo " bla bla word word1 =swhsw 123  " | awk -F"=" '{split($2,a," ");print a[2]}'
123
```

And how about you start reading up on how to use [sed/awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/) ?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is pure GNU SED:

```
export text=" bla bla word word1 = string1 string2 string3 ";
echo "$text" | sed 's/.*= \?[a-zA-Z0-9]* \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/';
```

i change a little bit the string because is possible to have more words, the rules will change if that word is not the last.

Lets explain this:

1. `.*=` : all characters before equal sign.
2. `.*= /?` : this is the main part, after equal i leave a blank
   space and i put the /?, this means one or zero ocurrences, dont know
   if you will leave a space here.
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` all ocurrences of a-z A-Z 0-9, the word (string1).
4. `\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)` get all ocurrencies of a-zA-z0-9 again, the second word.
5. `\).*` all the other stuff.
6. `/\1/` will output all the things you between \(\).

I hope this helps somebody.