# how to get line cut after a sign

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have a lines:

```
something ..fdfad ABCD info
fdsafsda fae faefdsa fABCD info23
```

I want get line after ABCD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308239/sed-how-to-get-the-second-word-string-after-separator-by-sed

Comment: is "ABCD" allowed to appear more than once in a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/.*ABCD //' file
info
info23
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your shell handle it:

```
line="something ..fdfad ABCD info"
printf "result:%s\n" "${line##*ABCD }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this

```
awk '{printf "%s\n", $NF}' FS="ABCD" myfile
```