# sed/awk + line manipulation

Tags: sed

I have two different questions(on both questions need to ignore spaces)

How to print all lines until "=" separator for example

```
    echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | sed/awk .....
```

Will print:

```
    bla bla girl man dog
```

the second question

How to print all lines from "=" until end of line

```
    echo " bla bla girl man dof = black white color bla 123 4" | sed/awk .....
```

Will print

```
    black white color bla 123 4
```

THX for help 
Lidia

Comment: You asked the same question like 5min ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308239/sed-how-to-get-the-second-word-string-after-separator-by-sed/3308264#3308264 , even commenting on what you wanted to do here.

Comment: no its deffrent please look on this case

Comment: :sniff sniff: smells like homework overflow

Comment: please dont say taht its not homework !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the first question:

```
sed 's/^ *\([^=]*\) *= *\(.*\) *$/\1/'
```

Answer to the second question:

```
sed 's/^ *\([^=]*\) *= *\(.*\) *$/\2/'
```

Explanation:

**`^ *\([^=]*\) *= *\(.*\) *$`** matches the whole line.  It contains two [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): first group captures everything up to the first `=` except boundary spaces, second group captures everything after the first `=` except for boundary spaces.  **`\1`** and **`\2`** are references to the capturing groups.

**EDIT** The above answer to the first question is incorrect, as it leaves trailing spaces.  A correct version should read:

```
sed 's/^ *\([^=]*\) *= *\(.*\) *$/\1/' | sed 's/ *$//'
```

There seems to be no way to make the `[^=]*` reluctant, hence two sed commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | awk -F '=' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

cut can help you.
cut cuts a line using a custom delimiter, and gives you any parts around it.

`echo " bla bla girl man dof = black white color bla 123 4" | cut -d= -f1` gives you the first part before a =

`echo " bla bla girl man dof = black white color bla 123 4" | cut -d= -f2` gives you the second part after a =

if you have more than one = one the line -f2- will give you everything after the first = (ignoring the second =).

Answer (score 0):

For the first, use

```
cut -d= -f1
```

For the second, use

```
cut -d= -f2-
```

But these solutions preserve spaces.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

First question:

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | sed -n '{s/\([^=]*\)=.*/\1/p}'
```

Second question:

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | sed -n '{s/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/p}'
```

---

With `awk`:

First question:

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | awk -F= '{print $1}'
```

Second quetion:

if you have exactly one `=` in each line:

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

---

Using `cut`

```
echo " bla bla girl man dog = black white color bla 123 4" | cut -d= -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Atmark](https://github.com/klen/atmark) its much more easy:

first

```
@ split = head trim_
```

second

```
@ split = tail trim_
```